# Is it safe to delete files in /dev/sda6? How can I delete them?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, mount

I need to make some space for my data and found some backup  in /dev/sda6/. I can't delete them using 'DEL' key. So is it safe to delete files in /dev/sda6/? If so, how can I delete them?

Is /dev/sda4/ is used for my dual boot? Is it possible to delete files in it under Ubuntu? Or should I log-into windows and then delete the files?

```
(base):data$ df -H
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            8.4G     0  8.4G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.7G  1.9M  1.7G   1% /run
/dev/sda7        82G   74G  4.1G  95% /
tmpfs           8.4G   94M  8.3G   2% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.3M  4.1k  5.3M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           8.4G     0  8.4G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0      148M  148M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/90
/dev/loop1       38M   38M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1198
/dev/loop2      1.1M  1.1M     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/61
/dev/loop3      4.0M  4.0M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/100
/dev/loop4       45M   45M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1313
/dev/loop5       93M   93M     0 100% /snap/core/7270
/dev/loop9      158M  158M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/67
/dev/loop7       58M   58M     0 100% /snap/core18/1055
/dev/loop8       58M   58M     0 100% /snap/core18/1066
/dev/loop11     158M  158M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/63
/dev/loop12     148M  148M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/88
/dev/loop13      16M   16M     0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/296
/dev/loop14     4.0M  4.0M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/95
/dev/loop6      190M  190M     0 100% /snap/spotify/36
/dev/loop10     190M  190M     0 100% /snap/spotify/35
/dev/loop15      16M   16M     0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/292
/dev/loop16     4.4M  4.4M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/406
/dev/sda2       101M   32M   70M  32% /boot/efi
tmpfs           1.7G  156k  1.7G   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sdb1       2.1T  521G  1.5T  27% /media/rmi/Seagate Backup Plus Drive
/dev/sda6       437G  253G  184G  58% /media/rmi/Data
/dev/sda4       462G  420G   43G  91% /media/rmi/Win10OS
```

Comment: How can we know what is in /media/rmi/Data ?   We can't peruse the files there, and even if we could, we'd be unlikely to know how important to you they are.  As for deleting them, I'd just `rm` them, but since we can't see the files we don't know the rights you have, or if elevated (`sudo`) privileges will be necessary, let alone if the file-system is read-write.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to make some space for my data

Where do you need it? If on your Ubuntu partition (/dev/sda7) removing anything not on sda7 is not going to get you anywhere.

These 3:

```
/dev/sdb1      
/dev/sda6      
/dev/sda4
```

are external partitions (since the mount point is in /media/). What you remove there does not create space on your Ubuntu disk.

> Is /dev/sda4/ is used for my dual boot?

That is impossible to tell from the information you give. The label in itself points to windows. The label "Data" is too generic so could be a windows partition (it could be C: and D:).

> Is it possible to delete files in it under Ubuntu?

Any disk/partition that is mounted as writable you can remove files from. Not all partitions from windows will be mounted as writable: if there is a hibernation file present Ubuntu will refuse to mount.

> Or should I log-into windows and then delete the files?

That is up to you to decide. I am of the opinion that you do things on the OS it belongs to. You repair windows from windows. You change things in windows from windows.

> So is it safe to delete files in /dev/sda6/? If so, how can I delete them?

Up to you to decide. But what do you mean with "safe to delete". You can delete anything if you want to. "Safe" is not a part of that. You can even delete windows from Ubuntu if you want. If it was *intended* is up for you to decide ;)